# Changing accuracy of decimal values in SQL

Tags: sql, decimal

I have a table where I don't have permission to change column datatype. But, I have to change the accuracy of column values of type decimal from (5,2) to (5,1). I already have 20 entries in that table for which I have to change the accuracy to 1 decimal place. Do I have to update each and every row individually or is there any way to change all values at one time?

Comment: You just said you don't have permission to change column datatype. Even you change 20 entries, new entries will still have two decimal point.

Comment: Execute an update query and Cast it to decimal(5,1), like SELECT CAST(@num AS DECIMAL(5,1)), and for new entries, you can use After Trigger to update values as soon as they inserted.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: And you can't put all valid decimal(5,1) values into a decimal(5,2) column. E.g. 1234.5 doesn't fit.

Comment: We use Microsoft SQL

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a statement like this if I understand your question properly

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET myDecimal=CAST(myDecimal AS DECIMAL(5,1))
```

(Where my "myDecimal" is the column name you want to update the data for)

This will update the data in place but not change the data type of the column itself.

Comment: The above query shows that the 20 rows affected but the values are still with 2 decimal places.

Comment: Sure - the datatype of the column is still 5,2 but the update will reduce the accuracy to 5,1 the 2nd decimal point value will be zero after the update. You will need to change the table column data type to drop off the 2nd decimal place completely.